# testing an angular js directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing

How would you test this angular test directive?

```
$scope.cancel = function () {
             $('#pp_bsktexit').modal('show');
};
```

something like this, i can test, it  does not seem too:

var nextScreenPath = 'C_HIST';

```
$scope.goBack = function() {                
            //sessionService.save($scope.sessionData);              
            $location.path(nextScreenPath);
}
```

and the test:

```
it('should return location path as nextScreenPath', function(){
            var nextScreenPath = 'C_HIST';
            expect($location.path()).toEqual('');
            scope.goBack();
            expect($location.path()).toEqual('/' + nextScreenPath);

});
```

but i can't quite transfer the logic/knowledge to test the original query. anyone got any ideas? will i need to mock something?

Answer (score 0):

So it seems your using jQuery directly which makes it problematic for mocking.

What you should do instead is use **angular.element**, which will automatically use jQuery behind the scenes if it exists.

Then in your test directives you would generally use spies:

**spyOn(element, '').**

There are several spyOn methods, for returning a fixed value or calling a fake function. Have a look at the jasmine documentation for spies:

http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies